# How can you create a self-contained build targetting Ubuntu on Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

The goal is to be able to run a shell file that will build my .Net project on a MacBook (Intel CPU).

I'm running the following command:

`dotnet build --restore --self-contained --runtime ubuntu.20.04-x64 --output "$TARGET" "$SOLUTION" --configuration Release`

I expect that I should be able to build a self contained solution that targets an ubuntu 20.04 server. Instead, I get the following error:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.306/Current/SolutionFile/ImportAfter/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(27,5): error NETSDK1134: Building a solution with a specific RuntimeIdentifier is not supported. If you would like to publish for a single RID, specify the RID at the individual project level instead. [/Users/myUser/Development/GIT/project/myProject/project.sln]

If I want to be able to run this through terminal and target different environments as needed, what am I missing?